# How do I approach sharing ng-template throughout my Angular app?

Tags: angular, templates

Assuming that I have a typeahead component in Angular that shows the lookup matches it receives from backend endpoint. I want to style the match items and I am able to do so via `ng-template`, `ngTemplateOutlet` and `ngTemplateOutletContext`.

No problem here.

The problem is - how do I apply DRY approach and make this ng-template re-usable, so that I don't have to paste it into each and every container that wants to use it?

**Updated:** At the same time, I want to be able to use the typeahead component for other type of entities which require another template.

I am not asking for code, I am asking about the general approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the desired HTML into a reusable component. Give that component a selector. Then use that selector in any HTML template that needs it.

Here is pm star, a component that displays stars instead of a numeric rating.

```
import { Component, OnChanges, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'pm-star',
    templateUrl: './star.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./star.component.css']
})
export class StarComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() rating: number;
    starWidth: number;
    @Output() ratingClicked: EventEmitter<string> =
            new EventEmitter<string>();

    ngOnChanges(): void {
        this.starWidth = this.rating * 86 / 5;
    }

    onClick(): void {
        this.ratingClicked.emit(`The rating ${this.rating} was clicked!`);
    }
}
```

So the code defined in this template can be included in any component that needs it:

```
 <pm-star [rating]='product.starRating'
      (ratingClicked)='onRatingClicked($event)'>
 </pm-star>
```

Comment: Thanks, and then if I want to use the same typeahead in another place but instead of looking up and presenting items of type A, want to look up nad present items of type B - how should I deliver the template of type B for binding?

Comment: Pass it in as the @input parameter. Check out the docs on building reusable (also called "child" or "nested" components here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction Or you can see how I built the Star Component in my Pluralsight course here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update

Comment: If you are looking for a way to use ng-template accross multiple components, create the content of your ng-template inside a component and then use it like : <ng-template #popContent><app-popover [cellValue]="cellValue"></app-popover></ng-template>