# Share ng-templates

Tags: angular, angular-template

Is it possible to share TemplateRef's across multiple components?

What I have see is to define the template inside a component, capture the template using ViewChild and then use that reference on that component or on one of it childs.

I want to provide this templates in a lib, so they can be used anywhere.

Comment: do you have any objections to using a component instead of a template?

Answer (score 0):

ng-template helps us to project the content. You can have a ngTemplateOutlet inside your library component and pass the ng-template from your main application component. This is known as content projection in Angular. 
You can learn with an example on my blog post here https://sanketmaru.github.io/posts/ng-template-use-case/

Comment: Right, and I'm doing that. What I want is to provide with the library some templates that can be used.

Comment: Then you would need to create a component with that template and share it across. Check an example here in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640867/how-do-i-approach-sharing-ng-template-throughout-my-angular-app