# How to make an html snippets library in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I can easily define a set of html snippets in an Angular template file such as

```
<ng-template #settingsSvgIcon>
  <svg ...>
  </svg>
</ng-template>
```

and then use these references IN THE SAME HTML file by using

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="settingsSvgIcon"></ng-container>
```

But I **cannot** use them in any other component's html template.

What I would like to do is create a component whose template is full of  declarations for all the common HTML snippets used throughout the document. Preferably using *ngTemplateOutlet and avoiding the agonizing @ViewChild to reference them. This component would be like a service with methods one can use everywhere but in this case it would be html blocks one could use everywhere.

Is this possible in Angular and if so, how does one do it?

I have looked at countless SO posts and even tried the BING AI's code suggestions and they all failed. I must be missing something, I just don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-templates` are usually used in a small footprint withing the same template; or to provide the template for parts of more elaborated components. To create a shareable template you would need to create or a component or a directive.

If you need to have a library of templates, you should be creating a library of angular components/directives instead.

To make a lib out of these, all you will need is to create one angular module per component/directive, and declare and export that single component/directive in this module.

This way when you need to use one of these components, all you need is to include the component's module into your app.

I suggest you create a folder structure like this:

```
libs
 |_ component 01
      component01.component.ts
      component01.component.html
      component01.component.scss
      component01.module.ts
 |...
```

and the module would look like:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [Component01],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [Component01],
})
export class Component01Module {}
```

This way you can fill your components/directives with plenty of outputs or inputs and/or services and share the necessary data to your heart's content.

Comment: If I understand you correctly I will need to make a component for each snippet I want to expose? If so, that is exactly what I was trying to avoid. I would need to create at minimum two files for each snippet. I tried the above but using just one component and putting all the snippets as <ng-template> elements in a single component hoping that I could resolve them using <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="settingsSvgIcon"> as I can in a single file. Alas it did not work. So in the end if that's the only way, I will have to be satsified with the single file use. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yes .. think we cannot share `ng-template`  elements between components. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45640998/4604645)  to a similar question also leads us towards building a separated component  to share templates.

Comment: I really wanted the snippets for resuse of my svg in line icons. I have a lot of them and each one is only about 5-10 lines, but they are full of ugly data paths which make the code hard to read. To create a component for each one of these would be ridiculous.

Comment: you could create one component with all these little templates and have a [NgSwitchCase](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase) directive configured where it "switches" on a component input variable. This should minimize the amount of small components